# Rails - PostgreSQL boolean where statement, ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a model that contains a boolean attribute, `Member` can be `admin`. When I create a new `Team` I want to set this value to true for the `Member` that have created that `Team`. When I used `SQLite` it worked fine. The line that causes the error looks like this:

```
def set_admin
  if self.members.admins.any? == false
    self.members.first.update_attributes admin: true
  end
end
```

My query `(members.admins)` that looks like this:

```
has_many :admins, -> { where("admin = 1") }, through: :members, source: :user
```

**Note**
I have also tried:

```
has_many :admins, -> { where(admin = true) }, through: :members, source: :user
```

But I get the same error:

The full error message looks like this:

`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean = integer LINE 1: ...s" WHERE "members"."team_id" = $1 AND "members"."admin" = 1 ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE "members"."team_id" = $1 AND "members"."admin" = 1`

And I'n not sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO it is just:

```
# in team.rb
has_many :admins, -> { where(admin: true) }, through: :members, source: :user
# or if you use postgresql's boolean datatype
has_many :admins, -> { where('admin = \'t\'') }, through: :members, source: :user

def set_admin
  members.first.update_attributes(admin: true) if admins.none?
end
```

Comment: Thanks, updating the set_admin made it work, but I had to escape the query as Зелёный wrote: `has_many :admins, -> { where('admin = \'t\'') }, through: :members, source: :user`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
has_many :admins, -> { where("admin = ?", true) }, through: :members, source: :user
```

sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "members" WHERE "members"."team_id" = $1 AND "members"."admin" = t
```

or try escape query:

```
has_many :admins, -> { where('admin = \'t\'') }, through: :members, source: :user
```

or type cast on integer:

```
has_many :admins, -> { where("admin = 1::int::bool") }, through: :members, source: :user
```

Reference: [`Postgres#datatype-boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both of your suggestions, but I get the same error.

Comment: @Anders what type column of `admin`? this should work :(

Comment: Thanks, got it to work together with @spickermann's answer. I had to escape it as you suggested: `has_many :admins, -> { where('admin = \'t\'') }, through: :members, source: :user`, but I also had to update my `set_admin` method as spickermanns answer.